# Xamarin code works fine on Android but not on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Both iOS and Android are using the same Xamarin code. Works fine on Android but not on iOS.

`List<string> la_liste_de_liens` contains URLs to podcasts such as `www.something.com/podcast1.mp3`, `www.something.com/podcast2.mp3` and `www.something.com/podcast3.mp3`.

When I click the first item (item 0 from list) it plays well.
When I click the second item (item 1 from list) it would not play at all.

```
        var les_liens = new List<string>();
        string[] num1 = ((IEnumerable)some_podcast).Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();
        var le_programme = Preferences.Get("prog", "default_value");

        Le_prog.Text = le_programme;
        Titre_episode.Text = num1[0];
        List<string> la_liste_de_liens = Preferences.Get("haha", 
        "default_value1").Split(',').ToList();
        var le_rang = Preferences.Get("rank", "default_value");            
        var url = la_liste_de_liens[int.Parse(le_rang)].ToString();
        Console.Out.WriteLine(la_liste_de_liens);
        Preferences.Set("le_url", url);
        List<string> la_liste_de_durees = Preferences.Get("durdur", 
        "default_value2").Split(',').ToList();
        var la_longueur = la_liste_de_durees[int.Parse(le_rang)].ToString();
        Preferences.Set("longueur", la_longueur);
        pause.ImageSource = "bouton_pause_bleu";
        //low.ImageSource = "bouton_low_bleu";
        //high.ImageSource = "bouton_high_bleu";            
    }
    private void play_pod(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //CrossMediaManager.Current.Volume.CurrentVolume = 30;
        pause.ImageSource = "bouton_pause_bleu";
        play.ImageSource = "bouton_play_vert";
        stop.ImageSource = "bouton_stop_bleu";
        //low.ImageSource = "bouton_low_bleu";
        //high.ImageSource = "bouton_high_bleu";            
        var le_link = Preferences.Get("le_url", "default_value");            
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(le_link);            
        var le_temps = Preferences.Get("longueur", "default_value");            
    }
```

I could not figure out why. Could anyone provide some insight on this?

Comment: If the question is 'why' in general way, then it is because the underlying code is completely different, so there is no reason why it couldn't happen especially if you use plugins that sometimes may be very amateurish... Also it is extremely likely that the problem is in the plugin, just I can't answer you whether it is a bug in the plugin or your app.

Comment: Thank you.   I will find a way to use a diffrent plugin to play media and i will see.